# go through each row returned by a ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have following code to execute a query on the Database. it returns a list of objects, one for each row result from the query:

```
function getcontent()
{
    var data = {
        "id": "<?php echo $stournid; ?>"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "response.php", 
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            //**************************** HERE!!!!
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

The response.php file contains this:

```
<?php
$id = "";
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    querydata($id);

  }
}

function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function querydata($id){

require_once('dbconfig.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Errore di connessione (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
    . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$myArray = array();

    if ($games = $mysqli->query("my query is here.. pretty long but working correctly.")){
        while($row = $games->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $myArray[] = $row;
        }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
}
?>
```

here is the returned data:

```
[{"id":"1435","location":"Merano","date":"2017-01-26","eventname":"Collaudo","machines":"|6|","id_tournament":"2","allowedcat":"|A||B||C||D|","category":"test 1","chartsize":"8","exclusive":"0","subscriptionsactive":"0","maxsubscriptions":"512","autoplay":"3","machinespergame":"1","id_subtournament":"14","id_gamer1":"57","id_gamer2":"55","called":"2","callreadytime":"13:08:07","starttime":"22:12:19","endtime":"22:20:03","id_winner":"57","id_loser":"55","playsequence":"00001","tabsequence":"A00010001","dest_winner":"B00010001-1","dest_loser":"C00010001-1","connectionname":"","p1name":"Calamante Lorenzo","p2name":"Badiali Maurizio"},
{"id":"1436","location":"Merano","date":"2017-01-26","eventname":"Collaudo","machines":"|4|","id_tournament":"2","allowedcat":"|A||B||C||D|","category":"test 1","chartsize":"8","exclusive":"0","subscriptionsactive":"0","maxsubscriptions":"512","autoplay":"3","machinespergame":"1","id_subtournament":"14","id_gamer1":null,"id_gamer2":null,"called":"0","callreadytime":"00:00:00","starttime":"00:00:00","endtime":"00:00:00","id_winner":"0","id_loser":"0","playsequence":"00015","tabsequence":"W00010001","dest_winner":"","dest_loser":"1","connectionname":"","p1name":null,"p2name":null}]
```

What I would like to do, is in the Javascript, go through all the returned lines one by one and updated some div's accordingly. I am having difficulties on how to iterate the returned lines.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How does the data look like? Post an example of that JSON file!

Comment: done, updated with data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function(response) {
    // redponse is an array of objects (so lets loop through it using forEach)
    response.forEach(function(row) {
        // row is a row (object) from the array
        var id = row.id;
        var location = row.location;
        var date = row.date;
        // ... you get the idea
        // do something with the current row (maybe create a div or table row ...)
    });
},
```

**Note:** [**Array.prototype.forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) is like a loop but better. Check the docs.

**Don't want to use forEach?**

If you don't want to use `forEach`, you can use an old `for` like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    // using for is not very pretty, hein?
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        // response[i] is the i-th row of the array
        var id = response[i].id;
        var location = response[i].location;
        var date = response[i].date;
        // ... you get the idea
        // do something with the current row (maybe create a div or table row ...)
    });
},
```